# Centos 7 auto unlock encrypted hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, automation, centos-7, decryption

I have a Centos 7 server, and i have chosen to encrypt the hard drive in case someone breaks into my home and tries to read the files on my hard drives by directly inserting them into his own computer. I would like Centos to not ask the key every time i boot up, because that would be a problem if the server restarts and i am not home.

Comment: Hmm. If he breaks in and the server is on then he can read the files anyway ... and if the server is off he can just steal it and turn it on ("I would like Centos to not ask the key every time i boot up")

Comment: He would need A password, because there is never an account logged in, when i'm away.

Answer (score 1):

So you really ***don't want*** whole drive encryption, you want the system to boot all by itself and only ask you to decrypt your home files.

Use eCrypsFS & an encrypted home. Mint/Ubuntu & I'm sure Debian can do that fairly easily, haven't tried CentOS to know for sure, but guessing it'll work 100%

Just install ecryptfs - maybe called ecryptfs-utils - and run

```
  ecryptfs-migrate-home
```

And if you already have system drive encryption, remove it or set a blank password

Comment: Should've started with "these aren't the droids you're looking for" ;-)